# JOOQ Model API: insertQuery and Postgres returning statement

Tags: jooq

With regular JOOQ's DSL, I retrieve `returning` values with something like:

```
val resultSet = dslContext
                .insertInto(ACCOUNTS)
                .columns(
                    ACCOUNTS.STATUS
                )
                .values(
                   model.status
                )
                .returning(
                    ACCOUNTS.ID
                )
                .fetch().intoResultSet()

resultSet.next()

resultSet.use {
   val id = resultSet.getLong(1)
   model.id = id
}
```

But how can I get the ResultSet of InsertQuery?:

```
defaultDslContext.insertQuery(POSTS).apply {
   addValue(POSTS.CONTENT, "foo")
   setReturning(POSTS.ID)
   //getSomehowResultSet() <= what do I do here?
}
```

For example the SelectQuery has `fetchResultSet` method on it.

Comment: I'm assuming this is using Kotlin (given the `apply` function). Is this really a requirement for you? After all, the model API isn't designed for use in a fluent style, and if you're not expecting that, then the `fetch().intoResultSet()` methods will work just the same as with the DSL API...

Comment: I generate sort of repository and have to use model api. InsertQuery hat only execute() method no fetch. Is there any way to get the result set from it?

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. I'll give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model API, the correct way to get returned results is:

```java
query.execute();
query.getReturnedRecords();
```